# How can I check if UIViewController "Did Dismiss"?

Tags: model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I would like to know, I have an UIButton in class A that does
`presentModalViewController:aViewController...`

I want to check when aViewController is dismissed.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you can't. there is no Notification (Bad Work apple).

But there is a solution :

use the viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, viewWillDesappear, viewDidDesappear family in the viewController that called the presentModalViewController function

the idea :

.h :

```
BOOL hasModal;
```

.m :

```
-(void)presentModal
{
   hasModal = YES;
   [self presentModalViewController:_viewController animated:YES];
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  if(hasModal)
  {
    // your code 
  }
}
```

Good luck ^^